# Node server is returning rotated images when I use background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, image

I have an application with node.js, and some images are stored in the server, but for some reason, when I search the image in my browser, looks good like:

> http://myurl.com/uploads/40884269-6854-9480-1a38-dc5744ad5d62.jpg

but when I use the  same image but with a css rule like:

```
<div  class="upload-grid" style="color:white; font-size:1em; text-align: center; background-color: #727272; background-image: url (http://myimage.jpg) !important;" >
</div>
```

the image is rotate.
How I can fix it?

Comment: The myurl image won't load for me. Anyway, are all the graphics rotated when you use them like that, or only one in particular?

Comment: I can't paste the url because is the url is without domain, only the ip, but I was reading that the photos not are diaplaying correctly for the photo metadata?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that was a screen shot or something, never mind me. Well, I know that a JOEG's metadata can say that it should be displayed in a different orientation, but I never experienced this problem firsthand. Are there any programs such as Photoshop that can tell you if the graphic does indeed contain such a flag?

Comment: That says a lot, I need read about it and chage the metadata of my files. Thanks.